# Symfony unrecognized provider property

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem when I'm trying to use the in_memory provider of symfony (3.4).

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        PortalBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        !php/const PortalBundle\Utils\UserMetaData::ROLE_GLOBAL_ADMIN: !php/const PortalBundle\Utils\UserMetaData::ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        fullname: test
                        password: admin

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: in_memory
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout: true
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

When i'm lauching the project, I got this error

```
 Unrecognized option "fullname" under "security.providers.in_memory.memory.users.admin"
```

The password property seems to be recognized.

I do have a fullname property in my user entity so I don't understand the problem.

```
/**
 * Full name of the entity.
 *
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="fullname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $fullname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user provider doesn't deal with extra data - just the username (here you've provided it as 'admin'), and a password - with an optional set of one or more roles.

```
# from https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: kitten
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                    ryan:
                        password: ryanpass
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to create a custom provider to get extra data (if I want to write the users the same way as your example in the config file) ?

Comment: Yes, you'll want a method of storing the info you need, that as explained on the Symfony Custom User Provider page, implements 'UserInterface' to mark it as a user, and it could also read/write data to the DB - but that is not required (just very usual).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `in_memory` provider you'll receive back an instance of `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`. This class has not `fullname` so an error is raised.